# uglifycss changes background color when minified

Tags: css, colors, background, minify, uglifycss

When I run the script to minify my css file using uglifycss the background color changes in the minified file. What can i do to make sure this doesn't happen?

filename.css:

```
{....
background: #bfaaaff
...}
```

filename.min.css:

`...;background:#bf;...`

Answer (score 0):

Your background color is invalid. It has 7 charaters instead of the 6 a hex color should have. Changing it to `background: #bfaaff` should do the trick.